# Missing some Firebase methods in previous versions

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to verify user's number with Firebase on iOS using a phone number using [this tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth). But I am use `Firebase 3.7.1` so, this: `Auth.auth().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: AuthAPNSTokenTypeProd)` and many another code samples not work for me: I couldn't even find `Auth` class, but when I found `FIRAuth.auth()` method I couldn't find `setAPNSToken` method, after this I found `FIRInstanceID.setAPNSToken()` but even now I have a problem, this code:

```
FIRInstanceID.setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: .Prod)
```

Causes an error:

> Extra argument 'type' in call

But this:

```
FIRInstanceID.setAPNSToken(deviceToken)
```

Causes this error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSData' to expected argument type
>   'FIRInstanceID'

**So, how can use this method in `Firebase 3.7.1`?**

P.S. I really can't find `Firebase 3.7.1` documentation, I can find docs only for the last version of Firebase. So, if someone can share a link with it, this will be the best help.

Answer (score 0):

Phone number authentication was only [introduced in Firebase SDK version 4.x](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios#4.0.0). It is not available on 3.x or earlier.